# Coordinate geometry and translations: rotations and composites oh my!

Tags: geometry

Here's the problem:

> Let $R_y$ be a reflection in the $y$-axis and $T : (x,y) \rightarrow (x-3,y+1)$. Which one of the following transformations is equivalent to $R_y \circ T$?

Here's my thought process:

- okay, so this means that first we perform $R_y$ on $(x,y)$, which gives us $(-x,y)$. Then we perform the transformation on $(-x,y)$

  - $T: (x,y) \to (x-3,y+1)$ (original translation)
  - $T: (-x,y) \to (-x-3,y+1)$ (now we substitute in the coordinates from $R_y$)

One good strategy is to substitute values for $x$ and $y$, so I did that, using the numbers $1$ and $$2.

- $(x,y) \to (1,2)$
- $(1,2)(R_y) \to (-1,2)$
- $((-1)-3,(2)+1) \to (-4,3)$

The issue is that my answer doesn't match any of the answer choices! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have an error in your calculation. $R_y(T)$ should be $(-(x-3),y+1)=(-x+3, y+1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're doing the operations in the wrong order. Note that $$(R_y\circ T)(x, y) = R_y(T(x, y)).$$ First you apply $T$, then $R_y$; you applied $R_y$ then applied $T$.

You can see the answer below (move your cursor over the grey box), but try it for yourself first.

> $(R_y\circ T)(x, y) = R_y(T(x, y)) = R_y(x-3, y+1) = (-x+3, y+1)$

Answer (score 0):

First thing first: the composite symbol $\circ$ is just "\circ".

Now: presumably by $R_y$, you mean the reflection in the y-axis.  The correct order of composition, if you're looking for $R_y \circ T$, is first do $T$, THEN do $R_y$.  Just remember that we should end up with $(R_y\circ T)(x)=R_y(T(x))$, and remember to apply the innermost function first.

With that in mind, we have
$$
T:(x,y) \rightarrow (x-3,y+1)\\
R_y: (x-3,y+1) \rightarrow (3-x,y+1)
$$
So, what we end up with is $(R_y\circ T)(x)=(3-x,y+1)$.  Hope that cleared things up!